# Ruby Class namespacing with modules: Why do I get NameError with double colons but not module blocks?

Tags: ruby

I am working with a lot of pre-existing files, classes, and modules and trying to come up with better namespacing for the different components of the framework. I've been using modules as a way to namespace mainly because this seems like the standard convention (and being able to 'include' different parts of the framework could be useful).

The problem is that there was a ton of classes underneath the global namespace that should exist underneath a module. For example, let's say there is a class that was simply defined as:

```
class FirstClass
  def meth
    puts "HELLO"
  end
end
```

But now I want to have this class within a module:

**Using Double Colons:**

```
module Foo; end

class Foo::FirstClass
  def meth
    puts 'HELLO'
  end
end
```

**Using Module Blocks:**

```
module Foo
  class FirstClass
    def meth
      puts 'HELLO'
    end
  end
```

Using double colons is a lot cleaner and also a lot easier to implement since I am changing many class definitions. Both of these ways work and I *thought* that they are both effectively the same thing, but evidently they are not. The double colon method seems to result in a different namespace within each class compared to the module block. For instance, with two classes underneath "Foo":

**Using Module Blocks:**

```
module Foo
  class FirstClass
    def meth
      puts 'HELLO'
    end
  end

  class SecondClass
    def meth
      FirstClass.new.meth
    end
  end
end

Foo::SecondClass.new.meth
```

**Using Double Colons:**

```
module Foo; end

class Foo::FirstClass
  def meth
    puts 'HELLO'
  end
end

class Foo::SecondClass
  def meth
    FirstClass.new.meth
  end
end

Foo::SecondClass.new.meth
```

The code works when using module blocks, but doesn't work with double colons. With the double colons, NameError is raised because it resolves `FirstClass` as `Foo::SecondClass::FirstClass` (instead of `Foo::FirstClass`), which doesn't exist.

This can easily be solved by including `Foo` in `SecondClass`, but how come this isn't done by default?

Note: I'm using Ruby 2.1.5, which I know is outdated, but I get the same results on repl.it with ruby 2.5.5p157: https://repl.it/@joep2/Colon-vs-Block-Namespacing

Comment: If, in the "Module Blocks" case, you insert the line `puts "constants = #{constants}"` as the last line of the module definition, you will see that 
`constants = [:SecondClass, :FirstClass]` is displayed. This tells you that, *from within the module definition*, you can reference the classes without the double-colons. That is, `FirstClass.new.meth` as `Foo::FirstClass.new.meth` (which could alternatively be used).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm aware of the ```Foo::FirstClass.new.meth``` syntax, but I want to avoid doing this since I am modifying pre-existing code, so changing every reference to FirstClass (which was previously a top-level class) would be a bit time consuming and it just doesn't look very clean. For now, I am simply putting ```include Foo``` underneath ```class Foo::FirstClass```  and in every other class within Foo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may seem counter-intuitive, but constant lookup in Ruby is done using current **lexical scope**, i.e. the current lexical nesting level (location in the source code), not the semantic nesting level.

This can be tested by inspecting `Module.nesting`, which prints the current lexical scope:

```
class Foo::SecondClass
  pp Module.nesting       # -> [Foo::SecondClass]
end

module Foo
  class SecondClass
    pp Module.nesting     # -> [Foo::SecondClass, Foo]
  end
end
```

Since Ruby uses this nesting level for symbol lookup, it means in the situation where you try to look up `FirstClass` within nesting `[Foo::SecondClass]`, Ruby will not find it.

However when you try to look it up within nesting `[Foo::SecondClass, Foo]`, it will find `FirstClass` under `Foo`, just like you expect.

To get around this, you could do:

```
class Foo::SecondClass
  def meth
    Foo::FirstClass.new.meth
  end
end
```

Which will now work as you expect, since you provided the necessary lookup hint for `FirstClass`, and told Ruby it is inside `Foo`.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the Module.nesting method is very helpful. It certainly helps me understand the "how" but I'm still curious about the "why." It's not very intuitive, especially since my previous understanding was that using module blocks was the same as double colons (this is what most resources seem to suggest). The only other topic I could find regarding this was [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/double-colon-vs-module-block/131186/9), but it still doesn't answer the "why"

Comment: Your sources are really bad. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: @max Evidently, yes, I didn't understand how it worked and I wasn't properly searching for what I needed. This is a great resource so thanks for sharing it. The style guide, however, still doesn't answer the "why" (nor does the [excellent article on constant lookup](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html) the style guide references)

Comment: Its because the scope resolution operator `::` does not reopen a module or class the same way the keywords do. Its was never intended to do so.

Comment: @max "Its was never intended to do so" - I understand that now, but I am wondering why it was designed this way and what the benefits are.

Comment: `class Foo` opens up the class and evaluates a block  (the class body) in that nesting (classes are also modules). `class Foo::SecondClass` is like calling `Foo::SecondClass = Class.new do` so of course the module nesting is different.

Comment: Here is an in depth discussion on this topic, it also has a section titled "Why?", that may help: https://medium.com/@hoffm/a-puzzle-about-ruby-constants-e958d15dbada

Comment: @Casper Thanks for the link. I've accepted your answer since it's the best possible answer to the question I asked. 

@max "so of course the module nesting is different" - perhaps this is due to my inexperience with other languages, but I still don't see why this is so obvious. Why is ```Foo``` not part of the lexical scope under ```Foo::SecondClass```.

I have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295287/why-does-ruby-not-add-parent-modules-to-the-lexical-scope-for-constant-lookup-wh) that asks about the "why" more specifically.