# Why does Ruby not add parent modules to the lexical scope for constant lookup when using double colons?

Tags: ruby

This question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273879/ruby-class-namespacing-with-modules-why-do-i-get-nameerror-with-double-colons-b) question. The answer helped me understand what was happening, but I am still questioning why.

When defining two classes within a module there are two ways to write it.

**Using Module Blocks:**

```
module Foo
  class FirstClass
    def meth
      puts 'HELLO'
    end
  end

  class SecondClass
    def meth
      FirstClass.new.meth
    end
  end
end

Foo::SecondClass.new.meth
```

**Using Double Colons:**

```
module Foo; end

class Foo::FirstClass
  def meth
    puts 'HELLO'
  end
end

class Foo::SecondClass
  def meth
    FirstClass.new.meth
  end
end

Foo::SecondClass.new.meth
```

Both ways work for class definition, but when using double colons you cannot directly lookup `FirstClass` inside of `SecondClass` without including `FirstClass` or writing `Foo::FirstClass`. This happens because `Foo` is not a part of the lexical scope of `SecondClass` when it's defined with double colons, which can be demonstrated by using `Module.nesting`.

Why is `Foo` not added to the lexical scope with double colons? In the context of the lower level Ruby [source code](https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/module.html), why does `ruby_cref` point only to `Foo::SecondClass` instead of `ruby_cref` pointing to `SecondClass` which then points to `Foo`?

**For Example:**

```
+---------+       +---------+
| nd_next | <-----+ nd_next | <----+  ruby_cref
| nd_clss |       | nd_clss |
+----+----+       +----+----+
     |                 |
     |                 |
     v                 v
    Foo            SecondClass
```

Comment: I suspect the answer to this question may require a trip into Matz's head. But I am eagerly awaiting an answer none the less, as I think it would be much more intuitive if it used the semantic scope for lookup. However, let's say you would patch Ruby to do this (how hard can it be? [*famous last words*]). It may break something, which would then probably also reveal the reason.

Comment: Pat Shaughnessy's excellent book "Ruby Under a Microscope" covers this in great detail. Highly recommended.

Comment: @JaredBeck I actually read the section on constant lookup before asking this question. It still leaves me with the question, "why does ```Foo::SecondClass``` never point to ```Foo``` (via ```nd_next``` member of the ```ruby_cref``` ```NODE``` struct)?

Answer (score 3):

Let me ask you the reverse question: why *would* it?

As you found in the last question, module nesting is important. For a quick intuitive example,

```
module Foo
  puts self       # executing in Foo context
  module Bar
    puts self     # executing in Foo::Bar context
  end
end
```

It is only modules (and its subclasses, such as `Class`) that can do this — change the execution context by nesting.

Now, over to your examples. The first snippet is effectively equivalent to:

```
module Foo
  # executing in Foo namespace context
  FirstClass = Class.new
  meth1 = proc do puts "HELLO" end
  FirstClass.define_method(:meth, meth1)
  SecondClass = Class.new
  meth2 = proc do FirstClass.new.meth end
  SecondClass.define_method(:meth, meth2)
  SecondClass.new.meth
end
```

Here, assuming we executed this at the `main` level, all of the references are relative to `::Foo`. When we write `FirstClass`, it is understood as `::Foo::FirstClass`.

The second snippet is effectively equivalent to

```
# executing in top namespace context
Foo = Module.new
Foo::FirstClass = Class.new
meth1 = proc do puts "HELLO" end
Foo::FirstClass.define_method(:meth, meth1)
Foo::SecondClass = Class.new
meth2 = proc do FirstClass.new.meth end        # ERROR
Foo::SecondClass.define_method(:meth, meth2)
Foo::SecondClass.new.meth
```

Written this way, it might be obvious why the second example does not work. If this was executed in `main`, then `Foo::FirstClass` that we defined is understood as `::Foo::FirstClass`. The `FirstClass` mention in the error line is understood as `::FirstClass`, which was never defined.

Comment: @Casper: How so? As I said, it should be obvious in the rewrite: `::FirstClass` is not defined. There is no way for the `proc` that is assigned to `meth2` to know it will end up as a method in a class in a `Foo` namespace.

Comment: To be clear: there is no OBVIOUS reason why `class Foo::SomeClass`, does not open the scope `Foo` and `SomeClass` separately, like it does in the case of `module Foo; class SomeClass`. It is just a syntactic choice that Matz made for some unknown reason.

Comment: @Casper There is no obvious reason why Ruby shouldn't sing you a lullaby when you exit `irb`. Having no reason not to do something is very different from having a reason to do something; this brings me to the top of my answer: why should it? I believe my rewrite makes sense; doing what you suggest would insert some additional heuristics there that would complicate things — with no obvious reason (in my opinion).

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't take it that way — but I don't think having ambiguous scope would be beneficial.

Comment: "is understood as ```::FirstClass```" - What is the benefit of this this implicitly being ```::FirstClass```? Why not determine the nesting based on scope of execution. Why not have this implicitly evaluate as ```self.class.const_get :FirstClass``` (and have ```Foo::SecondClass.const_get :FirstClass``` return ```Foo::FirstClass``` instead of a NameError for ```Foo::SecondClass::FirstClass```) and if we wanted to explicitly lookup the constant at the top level we write ```::FirstClass```.

Comment: "why should it?" - I think it would be more sensible for ```Foo::SecondClass.const_get :FirstClass``` to return ```Foo::FirstClass``` instead of a NameError on ```Foo::SecondClass::FirstClass```. Also, if we want to dynamically reference a constant in multiple classes across varying parent modules/classes, we have to to do something like ```proc { Kernel.const_get "#{self.class.to_s.split("::").first}::CONSTANT_NAME"}``` which gets increasingly difficult as you have more complex nesting structures. Finally we wouldn't need to write ```class Foo::SecondClass \ninclude Foo```.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to explicitly set the modules that are used for constant lookup. Here's an example of a class `MyClass` defined under a module `Foo`:

```
module Foo
  A = 'A in Foo'
  B = 'B in Foo'
  C = 'C in Foo'
end

module Foo
  class MyClass
    B = 'B in MyClass'

    p Module.nesting  #=> [Foo::MyClass, Foo]

    def self.abc
      [A, B, C]
    end
  end
end

Foo::MyClass.abc
#=> ["A in Foo", "B in MyClass", "C in Foo"]
```

The constants are resolved the way `Module.nesting` shows,  i.e. `A`, `B`, `C` are searched in `Foo::MyClass` and then in `Foo`.

---

Now for something more unusual. We can add a totally unrelated module `Bar::Baz` in-between `Foo::MyClass` and `Foo` for constant lookup:

```
module Foo
  A = 'A in Foo'
  B = 'B in Foo'
  C = 'C in Foo'
end

module Bar
  module Baz
    C = 'C in Bar::Baz'
  end
end

module Foo
  module ::Bar::Baz
    class Foo::MyClass
      B = 'B in MyClass'

      p Module.nesting  #=> [Foo::MyClass, Bar::Baz, Foo]

      def self.abc
        [A, B, C]
      end
    end
  end
end

Foo::MyClass.abc
#=> ["A in Foo", "B in MyClass", "C in Bar::Baz"]
```

I don't know if this has any real-world application, but it makes constant lookup extremely flexible. You can precisely select the modules you want to include (or exclude) for constant lookup and their order.

Comment: "You can precisely select the modules you want to include (or exclude)" - I have no qualms about _explicit_ constant lookup, but rather _implicit_ constant lookup. For example, I would expect ```Foo::MyClass.const_get :A``` to return ```'A in Foo'```, but it throws a ```NameError``` because ```Foo::MyClass::A``` is not defined.

Comment: @Joe_P `Foo::MyClass.const_get :A` _is_ explicit. It throws an error because `MyClass` doesn't define `A`. Implicit lookup means just writing `A` which uses the current nesting.

Comment: I see ```Foo::MyClass.const_get :A``` as being implicit because you are not using the namespace operator when referring to the constant. For example, simply writing ```A``` is implicit while writing ```::A```, ```Foo::A```, or ```Foo::MyClass::A``` is explicitly defining the namespace. In the case of ```Module#const_get```, ```Foo::MyClass.const_get "Foo::A"``` would be explicit where as ```Foo::MyClass.const_get "A"``` is implicit, and I want to know why it only tries to lookup the constant under ```Foo::MyClass``` and not ```Foo```

Comment: @Joe_P the current namespace / nesting is a transient property while Ruby is parsing the code (lexical scope). You can freely reopen the same class under different namespaces and have different constant lookup each time. And there's no way Ruby could retrieve that information afterwards. For example, in my second example, `C` evaluates to `Bar::Baz::C` within the `class` block, although `Bar::Baz` has no connection at all to `Foo` or `Foo::MyClass`.

Comment: "transient property while Ruby is parsing the code (lexical scope)" - Yes, but why? Why is ```Module.nesting``` ```[Foo::MyClass, Bar::Baz, Foo]``` instead of ```[Foo::MyClass, Foo, Bar::Baz, Bar ]```. The latter makes more sense and seems more natural, whereas the first seems more convoluted. Yes, it is more flexible in terms of implicit lookup, but we could easily specify ```Bar::Baz::C``` if we wanted to explicitly lookup the constant in ```Bar::Baz``` or dynamically skip modules by calling ```Module#const_get``` while iterating through ```Module.nesting```

Comment: @Joe_P you can just use the nested variant (`module Foo ; class FirstClass ; end ; end`). It works _exactly_ the way you want. The other variant (`module Foo::FirstClass`) requires you to specify the modules for constant lookup explicitly. This might seem complicated if you are just replicating the former variant. But if you want to set up a different kind of constant lookup, this syntax allows it – you can have it the way you want. Maybe it helps to think of the former variant as "automatic nesting" and of the latter variant as "manual nesting".

Comment: If you are writing code across multiple files (ie. each class within its own file) the latter is easier to write and looks a lot cleaner. In my opinion, if you want to setup a "different kind of constant lookup", this should be done via the code executing the constant lookup itself, rather than the lexical scope. I have yet to see any real benefits of lexical scope the current way it's implemented, and I have listed the disadvantages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295287#comment104821638_59297383)